# Tocar uma musica por vez em uma TAG de Audio no HTML5 que é criada dinamicamente com mesmo ID

Tags: javascript, css, html5, python-3.x, flask

Bom dia!

Estou com uma dúvida referente a estar trabalhando com áudio em uma aplicação Web, tenho um App feito em Python utilizando Flask que varre um determinado diretório que possui vários MP3, sendo assim eu crio dinamicamente as DIV contendo os Players  de Áudio e os mesmos possuem os mesmo ID.

Segue o Exemplo:

library_music
                     audio1.mp3
                    
                        
                            
                            Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                        
                    
                   
                  
                  
                    library_music
                     audio2.mp3
                    
                        
                            
                            Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                        
                    
                   
                  
                  
                    library_music
                     audio3.mp3
                    
                        
                            
                            Your browser does not support the audio tag.

A aplicação funciona perfeitamente, porém preciso que seja tocado uma única musica por vez, sendo assim acredito que o caminho seja utilizar JavaScript porém não sei como proceder neste caso que as TAGS são criadas dinamicamente com o mesmo ID.

Se alguém puder dar uma força eu agradeço!

Comment: *"eu crio dinamicamente as DIV contendo os Players de Áudio e os mesmos possuem os mesmo ID"* isso já está errado, o ID deve ser **único** não deve criar mais de um elemento com o mesmo ID, ao criar ou mude o ID ou não atribua um ID.

Comment: sobre a pargunta, o elemento `audio` tem um evento "ended" que é disparado quando termina de reproduzir o audio, pode usar esse evento para reproduzir o próximo audio

Comment: Certo a respeito do ID, tranquilo... Eu consigo deixar de usar o mesmo ID para cada um deles, só que no caso eu quero impedir que o usuário toque Players  em simultâneo, quando terminar a musica beleza, eu nem preciso iniciar a outra. Queria um caminho para trabalhar com essas regras se puder ajudar eu agradeço...

Comment: o mais simples seria ter um único elemento de audio, mas no seu caso pode tratar o evento "play" e cancelar caso outro audio já esteja sendo reproduzido

Comment: Mais ai no caso eu acesso qual propriedade da tag Áudio no Html ?